# Copy all values from one column in one table to column in other table that share same username

Tags: sql

I need to copy all values from column in one table into column in another table and make sure that username matches the values in the column. In both tables there is a column with username. I have tried:

```
insert into [Table1] (columnName)
select columnName
from [Table2]
where [Table1].username = [Table2].username]
```

However condition clause like that doesn't work. In what way should I write condition `[Table1].username = [Table2].username]`, to make sure to update values in right rows (where username is the same?)

Comment: Hello, what is your database?

Comment: You want UPDATE, not INSERT.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Answer (score 1):

You have write `UPDATE` query instead of `INSERT`

```
UPDATE T1
SET T1.columnName = T2.columnName
FROM [Table1] T1
JOIN [Table2] T2 ON T1.username = T2.username
```

Comment: @Roland, if it's working for you please accept the answer. It will help someone.